# segment object(leaf) which is on the white paper using image processing

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, segment

I want to get only leaf from an image.
The background is a normal white paper(A4) and there is some shadow.

I apply some method (structure element,edge detection using filter) but I cannot find the general way which can apply all the image.

these are examples.
[image: ex1]

[image: ex2]

Are there better methods for this problem??

thank you

another example.
[image: ex3]

and the result I got is
[image: ex3_result]

By using

```
hsv_I = rgb2hsv(I);
Is = hsv_I(:,:,2);
Is_d = imdilate(Is,strel('diamond',4));
Is_e = imerode(Is,strel('diamond',2));
Is_de = imerode(Is_d,strel('disk',2));
Is_def = imfill(Is_de,'holes');
Is_defe = imerode(Is_def,strel('disk',5));
```

Then Is_defe is a mask to segment
[image]

But the method that i did is very specific. I cannot use this in general.

Comment: Your code you've tried?

Comment: watershed segmentation. Considering there may be slightly difficult cases than this. For this, even simple color thresholding will work.

Comment: first, i use filter, such as sobel, laplacian, to apply it but there are too much noises using RGB space,HSV space.

Comment: another method that i use is structure element and apply to RGB , HSV space. the result is great but it can be used in some cases not general.

Comment: parag - could you give an related resource for me? or can I use "watershed segmentation to search?

Comment: @Marcin i's already added my code.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/marker-controlled-watershed-segmentation.html

Comment: See my edited answer, hope it helps

Comment: Can you assume that the leaf will be centered in the image and there will be some margins? It does happen in your example images, will it be like that for every image?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox, you could do as follows:

The code below first estimates the threshold with the function [`graythresh`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graythresh.html), thresholds the image and fills holes with the [`imfill`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfill.html) function. Suppose `I` is a cell containing your RGB images:

```
for k=1:length(I)
    t=graythresh(rgb2gray(I{k}));
    BW{k}=imfill(~im2bw(I{k}, t), 'holes');
    subplot(length(I),1,k), imshow(BW{k});
end
```

[image]

Comment: I contains 3 pictures and k is number of picture ,isn't it ?

Comment: thank for your idea,but i think that your result includes the shadow which i does not need.

Comment: @BOSS yes, `I` is a cell with 3 images in this case, hence `k` loops from 1 to 3. The loop is not strictly necessary for you, it's just to automate the process.

Comment: @BOSS than I would suggest to use only the green channel. Replace the first line of the loop with: `t=graythresh(I{k}(:,:,2));`